# Как в Yii, открыть php файл через браузер?

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor

Установил модуль YCM. В нем вшит CKEditor + CKFinder. Пытаюсь загрузить изображение, выдает ошибку:

> Невозможно обработать запрос
> "assets/c3da22c3/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php"

Собственно суть вопроса такова, этот файл существует, но Yii не хочет его открывать.

Comment: Одно слово: .htaccess

Comment: @astratyandmitry, код в студию